# Can I set the exact height and weight of a letter/character?

Tags: qgis

I would like to set the text to have letters 1,7 m high and 1,5 m wide.
Can I do that in QGIS?

Comment: What text element are you asking about (in composer)?

Comment: In layer view. I want to set it for labels

Answer (score 2):

You can set the text label size in map coordinate units (ie to be a fixed "on the ground" size that shrinks as you zoom) but you can't apply an arbitrary stretch to make characters exactly the size you want.

I think the best you can do is as follows:

- Set up a grid of polygons or lines with the spacing you want as guides.
- Create a label **using a monospaced font**
- Set the font size to be roughly the height you want.
- Adjust the font size until it fits the grid height.
- Now tweak the letter spacing until you get the text spaced out horizontally in your grid.

The important thing is to use a monospaced font, which is one where all the characters are the same fixed width (like most web browser text input boxes...).

Here's an example of the settings and some fixed height (10m) labels with adjusted spacing.

[image]